# How can I print a list of recursive, ordered, dependent tables for a specified MySQL table

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

```
Given: table dependencies in order (Generated by MySQL Foward Engineer script)
tableA, NULL
tableB, NULL
tableB, tableA
tableC, NULL
tableC, tableA
tableD, NULL
tableD, tableC
```

I have this MySQL database that has 40+ relational tables. So I wrote a little Node.js program that would list out tables and their dependencies.

*I'd like to know what are the dependent tables (recursively) and the order they need to be populated for a specified table.*

So for example, if I wanted to add a record to tableD:

```
tableD (relies on) tableC (which relies on) tableA
```

So in order to populate tableD, I'll need to insert records in this order:

```
tableA,
tableC,
tableD
```

I feel like this is not a new problem so there is probably something out there already that I'm missing.

So, another illustration: If I have a list of 40+ tables and I want to pick a table at the bottom of the list and it only requires 2 tables to be populated before I can populate the table, I don't want to populate all 40 tables if I don't have to.

Comment: In your example it looks like tableD is dependent both on NULL and tableC. What does that mean?

Comment: In my Node.js program I put a null for tables that didn't have dependencies, but that in turned put the NULL record for the ones that did have dependencies. I can try to remove that record for ones that do have dependencies since I am in control of that program.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about the way you are representing dependencies in your example, but in general this a graph problem known as topological sorting. You can find the topological sort order using depth-first search, which is simple to implement recursively. You just need to be careful of circular dependencies, for which there is no topological order. This reflects the fact that `a` can't require `b` while `b` also requires `a`.

To do this you can simply model your dependencies as an object where each key represents a table and it's value is an array of its dependencies. Then use a standard DFS algorithm to work from your start node until there's nothing left to discover. The order you discover nodes will be the opposite of your dependency graph, so we can just `unshift()` these into an array. The final array will be the order you should load your tables.

```js
let deps = {
    a: [], // a has no dependencies
    b: [],
    c: ['a'],
    d: ['a', 'b'], // d depends on a & b
    e: ['d', 'c'],
    f: ['g'],
    g: ['e']
}
function getDeps(node, visited = new Set(), discovered = new Set(), res = [] ) {
    visited.add(node)
    for (child of deps[node]) {
        if (discovered.has(child)) continue
        if (visited.has(child)) throw("circular dependency")
        discovered.add(child)
        getDeps(child, visited, discovered, res)
    } 
    res.unshift(node)
    return res
}

console.log(getDeps('g'))
```